# Google line chart remove background color

Tags: charts, google-visualization, linechart

I can't find the answer for this one on SO or in the google docs.
Considering the following configuration how can I remove this super annoying background? Desperately trying to find the right property in the docs without success: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

```
  chart: {
    type: 'LINE',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      colors: [colors.primary.fresh],
      // what property to target here? I've tried most...
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`areaOpacity: 0` is the option I think you are looking for...

HOWEVER, this option only works on Area charts, not Line charts.
not sure it will work for you.

---

see following Area chart, with the fill color removed.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0,  4000],
    [1,  3800],
    [2,  5600],
    [3,  5800],
    [4,  5400],
    [5,  5000]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'AreaChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      areaOpacity: 0
    }
  });
  chart.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

see following Line chart, with the fill color added (doesn't work).

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0,  4000],
    [1,  3800],
    [2,  5600],
    [3,  5800],
    [4,  5400],
    [5,  5000]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      areaOpacity: 0.3
    }
  });
  chart.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

and just for reference, see following Area chart, with the fill color added.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');
  data.addRows([
    [0,  4000],
    [1,  3800],
    [2,  5600],
    [3,  5800],
    [4,  5400],
    [5,  5000]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'AreaChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      areaOpacity: 0.3
    }
  });
  chart.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: are you using a third-party library to draw the google chart? `'LINE'` is not a valid chart type. it should be `'line'` or `'LineChart'`

Comment: Nailed it! Feels like looking for a needle in a haystack a lot of times when working with googles graphs...